# Disregard incorrect user input until correct input is received

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I'm having trouble with my code. I have to make a simple choice game and I need to have it so that if a user inputs an invalid option that it pauses the story until they choose a valid response. I tried wrapping the whole thing in a while(1==1) and entering invalid responses in he console window and it printed out "That wasn't an option" infinitely. How do I remedy this?? Thanks.

```
         // First choice, scene 1 if-statements
        while (1 == 1)
        {
            String firstScene = Console.ReadLine();
            firstScene = firstScene.Trim();
            String firstChoice = firstScene.ToLower();
            Console.WriteLine();

            if (firstChoice == "rudely")
            {
                assholeFactor++;
                Console.WriteLine(">>\"You're damn right it was! We've been working on this for years. I thought you'd be happy that all those hours at the office actually amounted to something.\" (Douche factor increased)");
                break;
            }
            if (firstChoice == "nicely")
            {
                niceFactor++;
                Console.WriteLine(">>\"No, it wasn't silly. I can see where you're coming from. I suspect there will be a lot of people with those same type of questions upon the release of the first model.\" (Nice factor increased)");
                break;
            }
            if (firstChoice == "silence")
            {
                judgement--;
                Console.WriteLine(">>You sip your wine and say nothing. (Judgement decreased)");
                break;
            }
            if (firstChoice != "rudely" || firstChoice != "nicely" || firstChoice != "silence")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That wasn't an option.");
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The while loop? I removed it but it was before the if(firstChoice) line.

Comment: It is just a simple bug, you are supposed to test firstChoice2, not firstChoice.   If you don't pick good variable names then you'll add bugs.

Comment: I thought C# allows `switch` on strings?

Comment: It does. I like if-statements :}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must re-read the user input into the variable *within* the loop before checking it's condition:

```
var input = ReadLine();
while (true) // or some other condition
{
    if (input=="...") { } ...

    input = ReadLine(); // again
}
```

Also, I loled at `assholeFactor++`

Comment: Better make it a do-while as you need one loop-cycle anyway.

Comment: Alright, so I applied the suggestion (improperly, I'm sure) but when I entered an invalid response the first time it did not return any message at all. I tried again within the same console window and it said "This wasn't an option". When I tried to enter a valid response it continued to say "This wasn't an option".

Comment: Debug through your code in step-by-step mode. I'm 100% sure you will find where your flow is flawed.

Comment: @khlr You can use `do-while`, or you can assign the condition variable to a value which will be accepted by the condition *before* the loop and only update within the loop (not applicable here, as the condition is just `true`), and you could make a dictionary of actions to call by their respective (hopefully enum members) choices values. The point of the answer was to explain why OP gets infinity times "Invalid option" without being able to input a new input, and generally how to approach the solution - while trying to *avoid* confusing OP and overwhelming him with the possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, I debugged and everything and it works now. There is one slight problem, though. I could probably figure it out but do you happen to know why it does the first occurrence of an invalid response doesn't prompt the message "That wasn't an option"? IMG in question. edit: jk I can't post images yet ;-; [link]http://imgur.com/9mtf66F

Comment: @crin You will have to update the code snippet in your question or link to a pastebin. As it stands, the code I see is not the code you're using, because then it wouldn't work at all. Either way, I'm sure another run-through with the debugger will clarify things for you, step by step.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I edited the code, debugged again, and found a solution to my problem... only to be met with another problem. I try to access the string firstChoice elsewhere in the code but no longer can because it's not universal and is declared in the while loop. In addition, when I make statements like "judgement--;" or "assholeFactor++;", that modified variable is no longer saved & I need to access it later in the code. I know this was not the initial Q but do you have a suggestion for what to do in that regard?

Comment: Any variable that should be remembered outside of the scope of the function, should simply be outside of the scope of the function. You can try turn them into members of the class which holds all the relevant methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this. Basically, you keep a flag to control the loop. Continue it until you get a correct input. Stop the loop by setting the flag, once you get a correct input.

```
string firstChoice = "getInputFromUser....";
var isCorrectInput = false;

do
{
    if (firstChoice == "rudely")
    {
        isCorrectInput = true; //stop further loop iteration
        assholeFactor++;
        .....
    }
    else if 
        ... //set isCorrectInput as well
    else
    {
        //if input didn't match options, continue loop
        Console.WriteLine("That wasn't an option. Enter again...");
        firstChoice = Console.ReadneLine(); //
    }
} while(!isCorrectInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag to check on each loop if the question has been correctly answered. Something like this:

```
var answered = false;
while(!answered) // Loop until the question has been correctly anwered
{
    var firstChoice = ReadLine();
    if (firstCoice == "rudely") 
    {
        assholeFactor++;
        Console.WriteLine(">>\"You're damn right it was! We've been working on this for years. I thought you'd be happy that all those hours at the office actually amounted to something.\" (Douche factor increased)");
        answered = true; // Question answered --> shouldn't keep asking
    }
    else if...
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That wasn't an option.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
    Dictionary<string,Tuple<string,Action>> Choices = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, Action>>();
    int assholeFactor = 0;
    int niceFactor    = 0;
    int judgement     = 0;

    Choices.Add("rudely" , new Tuple<string, Action>("You're damn right it w.."          , () => assholeFactor++ ));
    Choices.Add("nicely" , new Tuple<string, Action>("No, it wasn't silly. I ca.."       , () => niceFactor++    )); 
    Choices.Add("silence", new Tuple<string, Action>("You sip your wine and say nothing.", () => judgement--     ));

    do
    {          
        string option = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Choices.ContainsKey(option))
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(Choices[option].Item1);
            Choices[option].Item2();                    
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("That wasn't an option.");
    } while (true);
```